# Does OpenEBS Jiva support if underlying storagepool fs is ZFS?

Tags: kubernetes, zfs, openebs

When using jiva datadirhost on a ZFS mountpoint(with xattr enabled)  I got this

`time="2018-12-02T20:39:48Z" level=fatal msg="Error running start replica command: failed to find extents, error: invalid argument".`

If we create an ext4 zvol based storagepool it works. Is this expected behaviour? I am using Kubernetes 1.9.7 on ubuntu 16.04 with ZFS.

Comment: Extents are not used in ZFS, so that seems likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenEBS has two storage engines currently supported,

- cStor (Recommended)
- Jiva

Jiva volumes are created from local filesystem or mounted file-system, and can't consume the block device directly. This makes Jiva will work only with those file systems which provides extent mapping. ZFS does not support filefrag as of now that's why it gives above error.

On Other hand, cStor storage engine, volumes are created on a pool created on block devices. Storage pool create by cStor is native zpool(ZFS). You can get more details Concepts-> CASEngines from openEBS doc site.